# Kendo Numeric Textbox not showing increment buttons in IE11

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I have a numeric textbox that renders correctly in Chrome but not in IE11. This is how it appears in IE11:

[image: Rendered component]

Apart from the look, the buttons do not work either.

This is the html generating it:

```
<label for="length">Length:</label>
<kendo-numerictextbox formControlName="length" [min]="0" [max]="maxLength" [autoCorrect]="true" id="length"
    decimals="2" format="#.##'m'" placeholder="Length (meters)">
</kendo-numerictextbox>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem in the new Kendo UI ASP.MVC version.